# CFG using POS tags in NLTK

Tags: python, nlp, nltk

I am trying to check if a given sentence is *grammatical* using NLTK.

Ex:

> OK :   The whale licks the sadness
>
> NOT OK :   The best I ever had

I know that I could do POS tagging, then use a CFG parser and check that way, but I have yet to find a CFG that uses POS tags instead of actual words as terminal branches.

Is there a CFG that anyone can recommend? I think that making my own is silly, because I am not a linguist and will probably leave out important structures.

Also, my application is such that the system would ideally reject many sentences and only approve sentences it is extremely sure of.

Thanks :D

Comment: Did you see this related StackOverflow discussion?

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10252448/how-to-check-whether-a-sentence-is-correct-simple-grammar-check-in-python

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The terminal nodes of the CFG can be anything, even POS tags. As long as your phrasal rules recognize POS instead of words as the input, there shouldn't be a problem to declare the grammar with POS.

```
import nltk
# Define the cfg grammar.
grammar = nltk.parse_cfg("""
S -> NP VP
NP -> 'DT' 'NN'
VP -> 'VB'
VP -> 'VB' 'NN'
""")


# Make your POS sentence into a list of tokens.
sentence = "DT NN VB NN".split(" ")

# Load the grammar into the ChartParser.
cp = nltk.ChartParser(grammar)

# Generate and print the nbest_parse from the grammar given the sentence tokens.
for tree in cp.nbest_parse(sentence):
    print tree
```

Comment: To get the POS tags from the sentence, there are numerous POS taggers for english. e.g. http://code.google.com/p/hunpos/

Comment: I know how to get the POS tags, but how do I get a CFG for the English language that uses POS tags as terminals?

Comment: POS tag every sentence in the corpus, takes out the POS patterns that occurs the most frequently.

Comment: Is here function/class in NLTK which allows you to take the most common patterns in a corpus and construct a cfg? Or do you have to do it manually?

Comment: i can write a script that does that in around 5-6 lines of code, but i guess you should consider playing around with the corpora available from `nltk.download()` =)

Comment: Maybe I'm inept, but I'm not sure how to use the corpora in NLTK to do this...Could point me in the right direction? :D Thanks!

Comment: 1stly, install the corpus http://nltk.org/data.html. Then check the `Reading Tagged Corpora` section on http://nltk.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/doc/book/ch05.html