# generating grammar rules for nltk parse trees

Tags: python, nltk

If I have the sentence `"Mary saw a dog"` and the following:

```
pos_tags = ['NNP', 'VBD', 'DT', 'NN']
```

Is it possible to generate the grammar rules for this sentence so that a parse tree can be generated (grammar below are the grammar rules using `nltk.parse_cfg`)

```
sent = "Mary saw a dog".split()
rd_parser = nltk.RecursiveDescentParser(grammar)

for tree in rd_parser.nbest_parse(sent):
    print tree
```

Comment: POS tags do not imply any particular syntactic structure, so what you want is impossible on principle.

Comment: possible duplicate of [CFG using POS tags in NLTK](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15003136/cfg-using-pos-tags-in-nltk)

Comment: Couldn't I use NNP->"Mary", VBD->"saw", etc?

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
import nltk
# Define the cfg grammar.
grammar = nltk.parse_cfg("""
S -> NP VP
NP -> 'DT' 'NN'
VP -> 'VB'
VP -> 'VB' 'NN'
""")


# Make your POS sentence into a list of tokens.
sentence = "DT NN VB NN".split(" ")

# Load the grammar into the ChartParser.
cp = nltk.ChartParser(grammar)

# Generate and print the nbest_parse from the grammar given the sentence tokens.
for tree in cp.nbest_parse(sentence):
    print tree
```

But as @alexis highlighted, what you're asking for it rather impossible =)