# Understanding grammar for Parse trees

Tags: parsing, nlp, computer-science, stanford-nlp, grammar

I am just trying to understand a natural language interface for relational databases proposed by [Fei Li (2014)](http://www.google.co.uk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjKo7O5rLTXAhWIIuwKHe8nA88QFggpMAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.vldb.org%2Fpvldb%2Fvol8%2Fp73-li.pdf&usg=AOvVaw21lOyEjhU8_uoIhbUtmmOg) (available as [github project](https://github.com/DukeNLIDB/NLIDB)). Specifically I don't understand the grammar they define for a ParseTree of a natural language query to a database. This question is somewhat like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23849261/generating-grammar-rules-for-nltk-parse-trees) but with a more complex grammar.

Background: A natural language sentence can be parsed as ParseTree (common library for this is the [Stanford Parser](https://nlp.stanford.edu/software/stanford-dependencies.shtml)) which describes the grammatical relations of words in a sentence.

The grammar for a valid ParseTree is:

1. Q -> (SClause)(ComplexCondition)*
2. SClause -> SELECT + GNP
3. ComplexCondition -> ON + (leftSubtree*rightSubtree)
4. leftSubtree -> GNP
5. rightSubtree -> GNP | VN | MIN | MAX
6. GNP -> (FN + GNP) | NP
7. NP -> NN + (NN)*(condition)*
8. condition -> VN | (ON + VN)

where

- `Q` represents an entire query tree
- `+` a parent-child relationship
- `*` a sibling relationship
- `SN` is a SELECT node
- `ON` is an OPERATOR node (e.g. `=`, `<=`)
- `FN` is a FUNCTION node (e.g. `AVG`)
- `NN` is a NAME node (e.g. a column in a db table)
- `VN` is a VALUE node (i.e. a value in a column in a db table)
- `ComplexCondition` must have one `ON` with a `leftSubtree` and `rightSubtree`
- `NP` is one `NN` whose children are multiple `NN`s and conditions.

**My questions**:

1. why is `condition` defined as `VN` or (`ON`+`VN`)? This would mean that something like the digit `5` by itself can be a condition. Would make more sense of only the latter, i.e. (`ON`+`VN`) is a condition (e.g. `>5`)
2. How can a `rightSubtree` just be a function (e.g. `MIN`). Btw I am understanding the pipe `|` as logical or.
3. I understand that `GNP` is recursively defined but at a terminal node the `GNP` node must be just a `NP` node right? But a `NP` is defined as something that has children... HOW?!?!?!
4. The authors of the github project quoted above state: "Take a Value Node (`VN`) for example, according to the grammar, it is invalid if and only if it has children. I don't know how to infer this from the grammar

Thanks for the help