# Distinguishing well formed English sentences from "word salad"

Tags: nlp, stanford-nlp

I'm looking for a library easily usable from C++, Python or F#, which can distinguish well formed English sentences from "word salad". I tried [The Stanford Parser](http://nlp.stanford.edu:8080/parser/index.jsp) and unfortunately, it parsed this:

```
Some plants have with done stems animals with exercise that to predict?
```

without a complaint. I'm not looking for something very sophisticated, able to handle all possible corner cases. I only need to filter out an obvious nonsense.

Comment: Have a look at this question's second answer. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10252448/how-to-check-whether-a-sentence-is-correct-simple-grammar-check-in-python

Having a library check the sentence for grammatical and spelling errors, and not only try to find the most probable parse, should be the way to go.

Comment: @HugoMailhot Good suggestion, but it is not going to be a smooth sailing. I fed my test sentence to the [LanguageTool](https://www.languagetool.org/) and it passed with flying colors.

Answer (score 4):

Here is something I just stumbled upon:
[A general-purpose sentence-level nonsense detector](http://cs229.stanford.edu/proj2014/Ian%20Tenney,%20A%20General-Purpose%20Sentence-Level%20Nonsense%20Detector.pdf), by a Stanford student named Ian Tenney.

[Here is the code from the project, undocumented but available on GitHub.](https://github.com/renaud/nlp-nonsense)

If you want to develop your own solution based on this, I think you should pay attention the 4th group of features used, ie the language model, under section 3 "Features and preprocessing".

It might not suffice, but I think getting a probability score of each subsequences of length n is a good start. 3-grams like "plants have with", "have with done", "done stems animals", "stems animals with" and "that to predict" seem rather improbable, which could lead to a "nonsense" label on the whole sentence.

This method has the advantage of relying on a learned model rather than on a set of hand-made rules, which afaik is your other option. Many people would point you to [Chapter 8 of NLTK's manual](http://www.nltk.org/book/ch08.html), but I think that developing your own context-free grammar for general English is asking a bit much.

Comment: Code link is deprecated

Answer (score 3):

The paper was useful, but goes into too much depth for solving this problem. Here is the author's [basic approach](http://cs229.stanford.edu/proj2014/Ian%20Tenney,%20A%20General-Purpose%20Sentence-Level%20Nonsense%20Detector.pdf), heuristically:

1. Baseline sentence heuristic: first letter is Capitalized,
   and line ends with one of .?! (`1 feature`).
2. Number of characters, words, punctuation, digits, and named entities (from Stanford CoreNLP NER tagger), and normalized versions by text length (`10 features`).
3. Part-of-speech distributional tags: (#  / # words) for each Penn treebank tag (`45 features`).
4. Indicators for the part of speech tag of the first
   and last token in the text (`45x2 = 90 features`).
5. Language model raw score (s lm = log p(text))
   and normalized score (s¯lm = s lm / # words) (`2 features`).

However, after a lot of searching, the github repo only includes the tests and visualizations. The raw training and test data are not there. Here is his function for calculating these features:

(note: this uses pandas dataframes as df)

```
def make_basic_features(df):
    """Compute basic features."""

    df['f_nchars'] = df['__TEXT__'].map(len)
    df['f_nwords'] = df['word'].map(len)

    punct_counter = lambda s: sum(1 for c in s
                                  if (not c.isalnum())
                                      and not c in
                                        [" ", "\t"])
    df['f_npunct'] = df['__TEXT__'].map(punct_counter)
    df['f_rpunct'] = df['f_npunct'] / df['f_nchars']

    df['f_ndigit'] = df['__TEXT__'].map(lambda s: sum(1 for c in s
                                  if c.isdigit()))
    df['f_rdigit'] = df['f_ndigit'] / df['f_nchars']

    upper_counter = lambda s: sum(1 for c in s if c.isupper())
    df['f_nupper'] = df['__TEXT__'].map(upper_counter)
    df['f_rupper'] = df['f_nupper'] / df['f_nchars']

    df['f_nner'] = df['ner'].map(lambda ts: sum(1 for t in ts
                                              if t != 'O'))
    df['f_rner'] = df['f_nner'] / df['f_nwords']

    # Check standard sentence pattern:
    # if starts with capital, ends with .?!
    def check_sentence_pattern(s):
        ss = s.strip(r"""`"'""").strip()
        return s[0].isupper() and (s[-1] in '.?!')
    df['f_sentence_pattern'] = df['__TEXT__'].map(check_sentence_pattern)

    # Normalize any LM features
    # by dividing logscore by number of words
    lm_cols = {c:re.sub("_lmscore_", "_lmscore_norm_",c)
               for c in df.columns if c.startswith("f_lmscore")}
    for c,cnew in lm_cols.items():
        df[cnew] = df[c] / df['f_nwords']

    return df
```

So I guess that's a function you can use in this case. For the minimalist version:

```
raw = ["This is is a well-formed sentence","but this ain't a good sent","just a fragment"]
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame([{"__TEXT__":i, "word": i.split(), 'ner':[]} for i in raw])
```

the parser seems to want a list of the words, and named entities recognized (NER) using the Stanford CoreNLP library, which is written in Java. You can pass in nothing (an empty list `[]`) and the function do calculate everything else. You'll get back a dataframe (like a matrix) with all the features of sentences that you can then used to decide what to call "well formed" by the rules given.

Also, you don't HAVE to use pandas here. A list of dictionaries will also work. But the original code used pandas.

**Because this example involved a lot of steps, I've created a gist where I run through an example up to the point of producing a clean list of sentences and a dirty list of not-well-formed sentences**

**my gist:** https://gist.github.com/marcmaxson/4ccca7bacc72eb6bb6479caf4081cefb

This replaces the `Stanford CoreNLP` java library with `spacy` - a newer and easier to use python library that fills in the missing meta data, such as sentiment, named entities, and parts of speech used to determine if a sentence is well-formed. This runs under python 3.6, but could work under 2.7. all the libraries are backwards compatible.

Comment: AS I improve on this, I will next look for subject-verb in sentence structure, and sentences don't end with an adjective... stuff like that.