# Function to check (English language) grammar in R

Tags: r, nltk

Are there any R functions that receive a sentence/paragraph and return a boolean indicating whether that document is grammatically correct?

i.e.

```
grammar_check("I've had a good day!") 
# TRUE

grammar_check("ive have a good day") 
# FALSE
```

I have found some very advanced text capabilities in R (mostly used in machine learning / bag of words etc), for example those in the `caret` and `tm` packages, but I have not been able to find any function that can check grammar

Note that [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25142528/5783745) answer points to some python packages and web services, but are for extracting and stemming words, and are not in R

Also note: An informative comment on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10252472/5783745) answer points out that to write a rules-based function would take a whole team of people a very long time (since English is so idiosyncratic) - so this is not something that can be hacked together by an individual in a short amount of time

Comment: Never used it but maybe this package? https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/NLP and check out the full list: https://cran.r-project.org/web/views/NaturalLanguageProcessing.html