# Recreate a string from list of words

Tags: python, string, list, join

Given the following string:

```
mystring = "today is a very boring day"
```

And the list of words:

```
mylist1 = ["today", "is", "very boring", "today is a", "very boring day"]
mylist2 = ["today", "is", "today is a", "very boring" "very boring day"]
mylist3 = ["is", "a", "today is", "very boring", "very boring day"]
```

How can I create a function that helps me to `.join()` elements from any list in order to recreate `mystring`?

```
def string_from_list(mylist, mystring):
  return the_matching_string

matching_string1 = string_from_list(mylist1, mystring)
matching_string2 = string_from_list(mylist2, mystring)
matching_string3 = string_from_list(mylist3, mystring)

print(matching_string1)
# Today is a very boring day
print(matching_string2)
# Today is a very boring day
print(matching_string3)
# Today is a very boring day
```

Comment: What is the output of `string_form_list` if `mystring = "2022 is a very boring year" `?

Comment: How would this function know to not return `very boring day today is a`? What are the rules that you, as a human, would apply to this string to get back to the original sentence.

Comment: @j1-lee it's the result of print(). The result would imply that `mystring = "Today is a very boring day"` and that `matching_string="Today is a very boring day"`

Comment: @Laci that would return an `Error`

Comment: Yes, but you CANNOT reconstruct the original string from the list of words.  There is no combination that produces a match.  You can produce a match with lower case `today`, but not the original.  And indeed, what would be the point?  If you're just returning the original string, what have you learned?

Comment: @JNevill prolly I'd start by doing a `mystring.split()` to create indexes and to have the possibility to order it logically

Comment: @j1-lee I edited the question so it's more clear what I mean :)

Comment: In `mylist3`, how would you be able to tell that `a` should come after `is` in the unscrambled string?

Comment: Your logic works for the given mylist but can fail badly for other lists. Try eg ["A", 'safe',"life","is", "a", "life", "not worth living"].  How do you know which combination of elements of mylist  to take

Answer (score 3):

The solution to your problem as stated is simply:

```
mystring = "Today is a very boring day"
mylist = ["Today", "is", "very boring", "today is a", "very boring day"]

def string_from_list(mylist, mystring):
    return mystring

matching_string = string_from_list(mylist, mystring)
print(mystring == matching_string)  # True
```

i.e. passing the original `mystring` argument to `string_from_list` makes the problem of returning a `matching_string` such that `mystring == matching_string` trivial -- just ignore `mylist` and return `mystring`.

The more interesting problem is reconstructing `mystring` given only `mylist`.  This can be done by combining strings that are subsets of other strings, and joining what remains.

Since you need to combine strings case-insensitively (e.g. to combine `Today` with `today is a`), you can then loop back and use non-lowercase strings from the original list to "fix" the case-normalized combined string, yielding the original string.

```
def string_from_list(mylist: list[str]) -> str:
    # Reconstruct the string, normalized to lowercase.
    mystring = ' '.join(
        s for s in mylist if not any(
            s != t and s.lower() in t.lower() for t in mylist
        )
    )
    # Correct case using hints from original list.
    for s in mylist:
        mystring = mystring.replace(s.lower(), s)
    return mystring


mystring = "Today is a very boring day"
mylist = ["Today", "is", "very boring", "today is a", "very boring day"]

print(string_from_list(mylist))     # Today is a very boring day
matching_string = string_from_list(mylist)
print(mystring == matching_string)  # True
```

Comment: @wooooooo if you have `mystring` passed in as a parameter, and the goal is to return a string that's equivalent to `mystring`, why would you bother with `mylist`?  KISS.  If you have a function that *only* has `mylist` as a parameter (which is not the way that OP framed the question), then the problem is more interesting -- you can't just `join` the strings together, you have to combine the overlapping ones first to avoid duplicating words.

Comment: I finally understand the OP's question...

Comment: This doesn't work if you change the order of the words. I've edited my question to make it clearer

Comment: There's no solution that can cope with the words being scrambled arbitrarily.

Comment: @Samwise can you explain whats been done in `mystring.join()`.It would be better if you can explain by editing the answer.

Comment: **combining strings that are subsets of other strings, and joining what remains**

Answer (score 0):

```
mylist0= ["A", 'safe',"life","is", "a", "life", "not worth living"]
mylist1 = ["today", "is", "very boring", "today is a", "very boring day"]
mylist2 = ["today", "is", "today is a", "very boring" "very boring day"]
mylist3 = ["is", "a", "today is", "very boring", "very boring day"]
```

By just seeing the above list, we know that after joining it using `.join` function, we will a grammatically incorrect sentence.

What we can do is:

1. Using `request` module, to interact with grammar or sentence corrector API's from web and get the string.
2. Use a module named `language check` in Python to check your sentence and correct it.

Some useful links:

- [Wordtune](https://www.wordtune.com/?utm_source=google-search&utm_medium=cpc&utm_campaign=NonBranded-Search_India_EN&ad_set_name=WritingTool-Search_IND_EN_General&utm_term=writing%20checker&gclid=Cj0KCQiAu62QBhC7ARIsALXijXRdI-5iVcSXlwdvZReOl2UkHkZUhiroPh5lEUBt0gaviveew0q2rCQaArpLEALw_wcB#rewrite-demo) (*A sentence corrector, I have tried it and it works pretty well.*
- [Grammar check in python.](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/grammar-checker-in-python-using-language-check/)
- [Grammar check stack overflow.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10252448/how-to-check-whether-a-sentence-is-correct-simple-grammar-check-in-python)
- [Language check](https://pypi.org/project/language-check/)

Comment: You're using the original `mystring` to reconstruct `mystring`.  Why not just `return mystring`?  Everything else is essentially a no-op.

Comment: Oh yeah your right, didn't thought of it.