# Syntactic Checking

Tags: nlp, nltk, stanford-nlp

We have a paragraph of text that we want to check for syntactic correctness. We are using NLTK and all was good till POS tagging but then as we begin doing parsing we realized nltk still does not have a statistical parse like the [Stanford Parser](http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/lex-parser.shtml). NLTK allows us to make toy grammars which is inflexible.

So in a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6115677/english-grammar-for-parsing-in-nltk) user larsmans mentions using Stanford parser and then checking chunks based on probability. But stanford does not [recommend](http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/parser-faq.shtml#j) it.

Can you recommend us tools,algorithms,pointers,suggestions that can help to set us up on right path,to check syntax(of say average 20 words length sentences,preferably python).We found [this.](https://github.com/wavii/pfp)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can consider [Link Grammar Parser](http://www.link.cs.cmu.edu/link/index.html) which is used by AbiWord (word processor) for checking grammar. According to their [page](http://www.abisource.com/projects/link-grammar/):

> The AbiWord team had a concrete need - to integrate a grammar checking feature into AbiWord. The best choice, they felt, was to build upon Temperley et. al.'s successful Link Grammar project.

Comment: Thanks.We discovered the same too a few hours back.