# Extract ingredient content words from a text

Tags: python, pandas, nltk, pos-tagger

I should apologize first if this question was  already answered. I cant find it here. My problem is as follows. I have a pre curated list of words and I also have some unstructured text like this.

```
2 1/2 cups all-purpose flour
1 cup rolled oats
1/2 teaspoon ground ginger
1 cup chopped walnuts
1 teaspoon vanilla extract
1 teaspoon pumpkin pie spice
1 teaspoon celery oil
```

My list contains following matching keywords [flour,oat,ginger,walnut,celery,celery_oil,....].I want to convert the unstructured text in to my matching keyword list.Like in the following.

```
flour
oat
ginger
walnut
vanilla 
pumpkin
celery_oil
```

Can anyone suggest me a method to convert those items using python. Currently I have some experience about pandas. Thank You very much!

Comment: Try wordnet similarity. http://www.nltk.org/howto/wordnet.html. But this is a bad question other wise. It's almost a homework problem.

Comment: I don't understand... what's the expected output?

Comment: If you are under linux os. Consider the use of grep

Comment: Can you please be more specific? Maybe provide a sample input and expected output

Comment: @AnandJeyahar Actually this is more than a homework question. I just want this data set cleaned . Thank You for your reference.

Alfie sample in put is given above and the output is in below if you could see that.

Comment: @IsuraNirmal Given that you post the list somewhere, maybe we can write something simple to clean it up for you.

Comment: take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27234280/how-to-parse-sentences-based-on-lexical-content-phrases-with-python-nltk

Comment: I was testing this with pandas in a very simple way (no nltk). Is there any way to convert this problem in to pandas lamda function and reformat this to a new frame?