# Terms for basic NLP/logical parsing example

Tags: parsing, compilation, tree, nlp, logical-operators

Given the following clause:

```
Female or not White
```

Is the following tree the correct representation of this?

```
      OR
    /   \
female  NOT white
```

That is, would "not white" be one unit, or is it considered two?

Additionally, what are the following four elements usually called in parsing:

```
OR     -- (logical?)
female -- (variable name?)
NOT    -- (inversion? or is this also logical?)
TRUE   -- (for example, whether the value of female is true or not -- variable value?)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this code:

```
import spacy
nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_sm")
doc = nlp("Female or not White")
spacy.displacy.render(doc, style='dep')
```

Output:
[image]

So in your case, `Not` will be considered as inversion

Or you can refer here for sentence parsing- [how to get parse tree using python nltk?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42322902/how-to-get-parse-tree-using-python-nltk/42323459)

Comment: thanks, what does "ADJ", "CCONJ", "PART", and "CC" mean? Is there a glossary of terms for this?

Comment: Yes, these are POS, here you can refer- [https://spacy.io/usage/linguistic-features](https://spacy.io/usage/linguistic-features)

Comment: Using `spacy.explain('ADJ')` you get the explanation for each of the abbreviations, replace ADJ with the abbreviations